# Who first identified the universal $C^*$-algebra generated by an idempotent of norm at most $C$?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

So much is known about hermitian and non-hermitian idempotents in a $C^*$-algebra, that someone must have written down the following.

> **Theorem** The universal $C^*$-algebra generated by one element $x$ subject to the relations $x^2=x$ and $ \| x \| \leq C$  is isomorphic to 
>   $$
> \mathcal{I}_D=
> \left\{ 
> f\in C\left([0,D],\mathbf{M}_{2}(\mathbb{C})\right)
> \left|
> f(0)\in\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> \mathbb{C} & 0\\
> 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right]
> \right.
> \right\} 
> $$
>   where $D = \sqrt{C-1}$ and the  isomorphism is specified by 
>   $$
> x \mapsto
> \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 0\\
> t & 0
> \end{array}\right],
> $$

This is not hard to prove, and makes it easy to see why an idempotent is homotopic to a projection.

> Is there a reference for this result, that explicitly mentions a universal  $C^*$-algebra or that spells out the universal property?

Answer (score 6):

I almost found it: Example 4.4 in "Presentations and Tietze transformations
of C*-algebras" by Will Grilliette, New York J. Math. 18 (2012) 121--137. The generator in the concrete algebra is not explicit, and must not be 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
t & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$ 
as the length of the interval does not come out the same.

I am still interested in any earlier reference that might exist.

Comment: Shouldn't I lose point here, for having an intermittent memory and answering my own question?

Comment: Did you ever find an earlier reference than this? Or would you think it is reasonable to call this a “folklore” result?

Comment: @Chris Ramsey  I never found an older reference.  I think calling this folklore is fair.